# how can i make this button function without errors

Tags: javascript

I have written some code to try and get a button that when clicked sends the person to the top of the page. However, I am getting errors like ERROR.'$' is not defined.[no-undef]

```js
window.onload = function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 40){
      $('#topBtn').fadeIn();
    } else{
      $('#topBtn').fadeOut();
    }
    });

    $("#topBtn").click(function(){
    $('html ,body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    });
});
```

```css
#topBtn{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    font-size: 22px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #e74c3c;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Make sure you import jQuery.

Comment: Script tag is broken above, guessing it is a typo. Java is not short for JavaScript.

Comment: Do you realize you are using a version of jQuery that is ~8 years old?

Comment: Putting `$(document).ready()` inside of `window.onload` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your javascript to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       $(window).scroll(function(){
          if($(this).scrollTop() > 40){
            $('#topBtn').fadeIn();
          } else{
             $('#topBtn').fadeOut();
          }
       });

       $("#topBtn").click(function(){
          $('html ,body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
       });
});
```

You should not have the $(document).ready() inside the window.onload.